# Machine Learning (python) Saving a scaler in a model

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

I'm using the following scaler:

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(dataset_train), 
                              columns=dataset_train.columns, 
                              index=dataset_train.index)

X_train.sample(frac=1)

X_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(dataset_test), 
                             columns=dataset_test.columns, 
                             index=dataset_test.index)
```

The model that I'm using for anomaly detection is sequential().

I know how to save the model, but my question is how can I save the scaler in the model, so I can simply apply the model in a new df.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use-case for an sklearn pipeline. An sklearn pipeline allows you to chain preprocessing steps with your model. Most things you want to apply a `.fit()` method to can be put in an [sklearn pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html). This way when you persist the pipeline important information is captured within your saved model object. You can find more on the sklearn pipeline page. Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# creating an example dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
y = iris.target
dataset_train, dataset_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#example of creating and predicting with a sklearn pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([('scaler', MinMaxScaler()), ('rf', RandomForestClassifier())])
pipeline.fit(dataset_train, y_train)
pipeline.predict(dataset_test)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how to apply that. When I train the model I use fit_transform for the train set and then just transform for the test set (as you can see in my post). When I load the model for deployment (without training it again, of course), let's say, in a new notebook, I have to use the scaler for the test set, but I can't use just transform, I must fit it and then the result is different. That's why I'm trying to apply the saved model including the saved scaler to test df (because as I said, I will deploy the model).

Comment: @Nicolás, the predict statement on the pipeline first transforms then applies the model in one shot removing the need to individually transform using the scalar then predicting using the model. fit_transform() is helper function that applies the fit then the transform. Using pipeline is like using fit for all of your stps that you can later transform in one pass. Do you need the transformed training data outside of passing it to your model?

Comment: I understand. Yes, I need the transformed training data. As you can see, I'm using a sequential model (Keras) and I don't know how to put that model in the sklearn pipeline.

Comment: @Nicolás, Most of my work is not deep learning, so I don't have a precise answer to your question, but it looks like there is scikeras, which allows you to use sklearn wrappers around keras models. I found an example here in the quickstart section of scikeras https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew. I'm trying to understand the pipeline. In the meantime, I could save and load the scaler. It is not the optimal solution, but it works for me.